# Display different colors based on column value

Tags: php

I am fetching values from DB & displaying in php page.

**1st** row value : **attempted**

**2nd** row value : **not**

```
echo $orderrecords[$k]["attempted"];
```

[image]

now based on column [ attempted ] value, i want to display different colors . So when i tried below code, instead of displaying different colors , both rows are displaying value : **attempted**

```
if($orderrecords[$k]["attempted"]="attempted")
{
echo '<div style="color: red;">'.$orderrecords[$k]["attempted"].'</div>';
}

else
{
echo '<div style="color: black;">'.$orderrecords[$k]["attempted"].'</div>';
}
```

[image]

Comment: try `if($orderrecords[$k]["attempted"]==="attempted")`,

`===` is used to compare same type and same value, whereas `=` is just assignmenta nd hence everytime you're assigning value `attemped` to the variable.

Comment: @moghya please post your comment as answer.....

Comment: you are using one = instead of two in your if-condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `if($orderrecords[$k]["attempted"]==="attempted")`,

`===` is used to compare same type and same value, whereas `=` is just assignment and hence every time you're assigning value `attemped` to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not comparing the value in your if-condition. You are setting the value of $orderrecords[$k]["attempted"] in your if-condition.

```
if($orderrecords[$k]["attempted"] = "attempted")
```

will always be true

```
if($orderrecords[$k]["attempted"] == "attempted")
```

will be true, if the value of $orderrecords[$k]["attempted"] is "attempted"

```
if($orderrecords[$k]["attempted"] === "attempted")
```

will be true, if the value of $orderrecords[$k]["attempted"] is "attempted" and the type of $orderrecords[$k]["attempted"] is a string